# Javascript Change function to check multiple id's

Tags: javascript, php, function, getid3

I would like the below functions to check for multiple product id's `!==` (1427, 1428, 1429). What is the best approach?

Thank you.

```
//add multistep
add_action('wapf_before_wrapper', 'wapf_before_wrapper');
function wapf_before_wrapper($product) {
    if($product->get_id() !==1427)
                return;
    ?>
    <div class="wapf-progress">
        <div class="wapf-progress-bar"></div>
        <div class="wapf-progress-steps"></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('wapf_before_product_totals', 'wapf_before_product_totals');
function wapf_before_product_totals($product){
    if($product->get_id() !==1427)
                return;
    ?>
    <div class="wapf_step_buttons">
        <button class="button wapf_btn_prev" style="display:none">Previous</button>
        <button class="button wapf_btn_next">Next</button>
    </div>
    <?php
} 
//end multistep
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about php or JavaScript?

The question title asks about JavaScript, for which I would use

```
if(![1427, 1428, 1429].includes(product.id)) { }
```

But your code example is php, which I don't know as well, but I believe it has `in_array`, so something like this might work

```
$ids = array(1427, 1428, 1429)
if (in_array($product->get_id(), $ids) { }
```